# Fit Bootstrap "Linked Items" to content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a set of Bootstrap "Linked Items" ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/MSVT4/1/)).

```
<div class="list-group">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item">Project 1</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item">Project 2</a>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="list-group-item">Project 3 has slightly longer text</a>
</div>
```

Right now, the rows expand to 100% of the page width. How can I fit the width to the text content? I want it to be as narrow as possible without cropping or wrapping the text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an override of the boostrap css :

```
.list-group {
    display: table;
}
```